# MySQL remove part of string

Tags: mysql

I have a column name with string like this:

```
Animale Masculino Eau Toilette 30ml
Polo Black Eau Toilette 200ml
```

They all have the same pattern at the end (30ml, 50ml, 100ml, 200ml).

I need to get:

```
Animale Masculino Eau Toilette
Polo Black Eau Toilette
```

How can I do this with MySQL?

Comment: I think REGEXP_SUBSTR is not available in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Gordon answer, I got it the result with the query below:

```
SELECT LEFT(nome, LENGTH(nome) - LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(nome))) from produtos
```

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple way is:

```
select replace(col, substring_index(col, ' ', -1), '')
```

But that doesn't work all the time (the last "word" could be repeated in the column).  You want everything up to the last space.

```
select left(col, instr(reverse(col), ' ') + 1)
```

Comment: Hi Gordon! Your second query return only the first character (A, P)

Comment: @Ailton . . . It should do the right thing with the arguments in the right order.